# Automatically trim white spaces with Yup and Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I am using a Formik React Form and Yup validation defined on a schema:

```
export const Contact = yup.object<IContact>().shape({
  contactName: yup
    .string()
    .trim('The contact name cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
    .strict(true)
    .min(1, 'The contact name needs to be at least 1 char')
    .max(512, 'The contact name cannot exceed 512 char')
    .required('The contact Name is required'),
});
```

Is there a way to have Yup trim white spaces without showing a message?  So automatically trimming the spaces when a form is submitted?

Comment: can you show your complete code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there a way to have Yup trim white spaces without showing a message

Not in a single transform. The yup transform used by formik is only for validation. 
You can create a seperate transform to use before passing the data, but its simpler to just `valueToUse = userValue.trim()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Ill probably end up just showing the message for now on submit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
onSubmit={(values) => {
  const castValues = Contact.cast(values)
})
```

reference:
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/473#issuecomment-499476056

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm after. I know it can be done this way but the question was around doing it automatically. So the idea was to do it without manual code manipulation. I created a my own separate transform to do this.

Comment: what is the `Contact`?

Comment: Schema Validation

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `onBlur()` event. Then trim the string to actually fix any trailing or leading spaces:

```
onBlur={() => setFieldValue('email', values.)}
```

Additionally, to trimming for Yup for validation:

```
export const Contact = yup.object<IContact>().shape({
  contactName: yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .strict(true)
    .min(1, 'The contact name needs to be at least 1 char')
    .max(512, 'The contact name cannot exceed 512 char')
    .required('The contact Name is required'),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve automatic removal of white spaces in an email field by overriding the `onChange` method from `formik` object. This is not the best solution to this but it works fine, especially where spaces are not allowed anywhere in the input field.

```js
const { errors, touched, getFieldProps } = formik;

const { onChange } = getFieldProps('email');

const emailFieldProps = {
  ...getFieldProps('email'),
  onChange: (e) => {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.trim();
    onChange(e);
  },
};
  
return (
  ...
    <TextField
      {...emailFieldProps}
      error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
      helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
    />
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also trim entered text on the go to completely limit user from using spaces at the end (example uses react native components):

```
const {handleSubmit, values, errors} =
    useFormik({
        validationSchema: EmailSchema(),
        initialValues: {email: ''},
        onSubmit: values => tryLogin(values.email)
    })

...

<TextInput
    value={values.email}
    onChangeText={text => handleChange('email')(text.trim())}
    error={errors.email}
/>

<Button title='SUBMIT' onPress={handleSubmit} />
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as the question is how to Automatically trim white spaces with Yup and Formik.